# how to fix the 'Cannot read property 'architect' of undefined' error in add the Nx in an existing angular 7 workspace

Tags: angular7, nomachine-nx

### I want to add the Nx workspace to an Existing Angular CLI workspace. but when run 'ng add @nrwl/workspace' command, this error will occur:

Skipping installation: Package already installed

### Cannot read property 'architect' of undefined

please help to find the answer

thank you so much